# Is there a better way to check existence of object's property?

Tags: coffeescript

I have this`if` condition.

`if object.fruit and object.fruit isnt 'mango'`

How can `?` be utilised here? I tried using `if object.fruit? isnt 'mango'`, but condition passes when `object` is empty object.

Comment: This would work `if object?.fruit isnt 'mango'`

Comment: @RahilWazir: No, `object?.fruit` is `object` is there before trying to access its `fruit` property, it doesn't have anything to do with `object` being empty or having a `fruit` property.

Comment: @muistooshort Right, and if object is empty `object.fruit` will return `undefined` which won't be equal to `mango` so its not worth checking `object.fruit` to be truthy as well I think.

Comment: @RahilWazir In this instance i know for sure that `object` is empty object at least. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check for three things:

1. Ensure the object exists: `object?`
2. Ensure the object has the key you're looking for: `key of object`
3. Test for the key value: `object.key isnt 'mango'`

All together that's:

`if object? and "fruit" of object and object.fruit isnt 'mango'`

You can play around with the values of `obj` in this demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLOMpm

Comment: `'prop' of object` is what I was looking for. thanks